# Exception in declaring a json with dynamic values in Jenkinsfile

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
def props = readJSON text: [ 'buildName':"${params.buildName}",   'targetRepo':"${params.artifactoryReleases}"]
echo props.buildName
echo props.targetRepo
```

Getting the following error

> org.kohsuke.stapler.NoStaplerConstructorException: There's no @DataBoundConstructor on any constructor of class java.lang.String
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.ClassDescriptor.loadConstructorParamNames(ClassDescriptor.java:265)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.(DescribableModel.java:122)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:380)
>
> Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {text={buildName=alu-rp, targetRepo=na-generic-releases}} for ReadJSONStep(file?: String, text?: String)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:264)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.newInstance(StepDescriptor.java:201)

Comment: You need to pass a string but you are passing a Map object to the text parameter. It should be called  like the examples here https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readjson-code-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace

Answer (score 13):

Since your `props` are in JSON, you need to convert it to string in order to echo it

Try: `echo props.toString()`

You can also use `print` instead, conversion to string is not necessary: 
`print props`

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

final def buildName = "master"
final def artifactoryReleases = "1.0"
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Init') {
        steps {
            script{
                def props = readJSON text: '{ "buildName": "'+"${buildName}"+'" ,"targetRepo":"'+"${artifactoryReleases}" +'" }'
                echo props.buildName
                echo props.targetRepo
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```